# How to fix duplicate key value violates unique constraint and customize "Add User" section in django admin panel?

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-models, django-admin

I have customized my user model.I have added many other fields in the user model.When I try to add a user by clicking the button "Add User" on the admin panel of Django .The following error occurs.
And How can I customize this "Add user" section. I want to add more fields here.
[image: Imgur]

```
IntegrityError at /admin/accounts/user/add/
duplicate key value violates unique constraint "accounts_user_email_key"
DETAIL:  Key (email)=() already exists.
```

I am using django2.2 and currently I am learning complex things in django.I have customized my user model .When I try to add a user by clicking this "Add user" in the admin panel of django this error occurs.

```
IntegrityError at /admin/accounts/user/add/
duplicate key value violates unique constraint "accounts_user_email_key"
DETAIL:  Key (email)=() already exists.
Request Method: POST
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/accounts/user/add/
Django Version: 2.2
Exception Type: IntegrityError
Exception Value:    
duplicate key value violates unique constraint "accounts_user_email_key"
DETAIL:  Key (email)=() already exists.
Exception Location: C:\Program Files\Anaconda\envs\DjangoEnv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py in _execute, line 84
Python Executable:  C:\Program Files\Anaconda\envs\DjangoEnv\python.exe
Python Version: 3.7.3
Python Path:    
['E:\\Project\\ProductHuntSite',
 'C:\\Program Files\\Anaconda\\envs\\DjangoEnv\\python37.zip',
 'C:\\Program Files\\Anaconda\\envs\\DjangoEnv\\DLLs',
 'C:\\Program Files\\Anaconda\\envs\\DjangoEnv\\lib',
 'C:\\Program Files\\Anaconda\\envs\\DjangoEnv',
 'C:\\Users\\khana\\AppData\\Roaming\\Python\\Python37\\site-packages',
 'C:\\Program Files\\Anaconda\\envs\\DjangoEnv\\lib\\site-packages']
Server time:    Thu, 1 Aug 2019 22:11:22 +0600
```

This is my code.

```py
class UserManager(BaseUserManager):
     def create_user(self, username, email, firstname, lastname, profile_photo,mobile_phone_number, password=None, is_staff=False, is_active=True, is_admin=False, is_moderator=False):
        if not email:
            raise ValueError("User must have an Email")
        if not username:
            raise ValueError("User must have an Username")
        if not password:
            raise ValueError("User must have an Password")
        if not firstname:
            raise ValueError("User must have an Firstname")            
        if not lastname:
            raise ValueError("User must have an Lastname")

        user_obj = self.model(username = username,
                                email = email)
        user_obj.set_password(password)
        user_obj.email = email
        user_obj.firstname = firstname
        user_obj.lastname = lastname
        user_obj.profile_photo = profile_photo
        user_obj.mobile_phone_number = mobile_phone_number
        user_obj.createdAccount = django.utils.timezone.datetime.now
        user_obj.staff = is_staff
        user_obj.admin = is_admin
        user_obj.active = is_active
        user_obj.moderator = is_moderator
        user_obj.save(using=self._db)

        return user_obj
    def create_staffuser(self, username, email, firstname, lastname,mobile_phone_number, password=None):
        user = self.create_user(
            username,
            email,
            firstname,
            lastname,
            mobile_phone_number,
            password=password,
            is_staff=True
        )
        return user    
    def create_moderator(self, username, email, firstname, lastname,mobile_phone_number, password=None):
        user = self.create_user(
            username,
            email,
            firstname,
            lastname,
            mobile_phone_number,
            password=password,
            is_staff=True,
            is_admin=True,
            is_moderator=True
        )
        return user

    def create_superuser(self, username, email, firstname, lastname,mobile_phone_number, password=None):
        user = self.create_user(
            username,
            email,
            firstname,
            lastname,
            mobile_phone_number,
            password=password,
            is_staff=True,
            is_admin=True,
            is_moderator=True
        )
        return user      
class User(AbstractBaseUser):
    username = models.CharField(max_length=200, unique=True)
    firstname = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    lastname = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    email = models.EmailField(unique=True)
    mobile_phone_number = models.CharField(max_length=20, unique=True)
    profile_photo = models.ImageField(default='media/default.png', upload_to = user_directory_path)
    active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    admin = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    moderator = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    date_joined = models.DateTimeField(_('date joined'), default=timezone.now)
    USERNAME_FIELD = 'username'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['firstname','lastname','email','mobile_phone_number']
    objects = UserManager()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.username
    def has_perm(self, perm, obj=None):
        return True
    def has_module_perms(self, app_label):
        return True    
    @property
    def is_staff(self):
        return self.staff
    @property
    def is_active(self):
        return self.active
    @property
    def is_admin(self):
        return self.admin
    @property
    def is_moderator(self):
        return self.moderator
```

I tried to find solutions about it but I found none.

Comment: Well the `email = ...` field is a `unique=True` field.  But you used `()` twice.

Comment: You have email as a unique value so if you try to create multiple users with the same email you will get this error. If you want users to be able to have the same email then remove `unique=True` from email, otherwise try adding users with different emails.

Comment: does the added email exist ?